facing the issue with a corrupted file(Excel) after downloading from SharePoint using graph api java code
I am trying download the excel file from share point . I am able to download the file into my local system from SharePoint app. but, when I try to open the downloaded excel file it is saying that file got corrupted not able to open the file. and also file size got increasing when downloading.
I am using code like below.
// Fetch file content as InputStream

InputStream inputStream = graphClient
                .sites(siteId)
                .drives(driveId)
                .root()
                .itemWithPath(filePath)
                .content()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();

if (inputStream == null) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to fetch file content from SharePoint.");
}

// Read InputStream into byte array
byte[] fileBytes = inputStream.readAllBytes();
logger.info("Downloaded " + fileBytes.length + " bytes.");

// Save the byte array as a file
Path destinationPath = Paths.get(localFilePath);
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath.toFile())) {
    fos.write(fileBytes);
    logger.info("File saved to " + localFilePath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.severe("Error saving the file: " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}

and also I have tried with bytes like belwo code.
try {
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadPath.toFile()));
    //FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadPath.toFile());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024]; // Buffer size (8 KB)
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }

    outputStream.flush();
    logger.info("File downloaded successfully to: " + downloadPath.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error while saving the file to disk: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}

please help me on this issue, is there any other way to download the file. The main issue I am not able to open files like excel and pdf.
also I have tried below code
try {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(downloadPath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING));
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadPath.toFile()));
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = bis.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        bos.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    outputStream.flush();
    logger.info("File downloaded successfully to: " + downloadPath.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error while saving the file to disk: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}


fos.write is not guaranteed to write all bytes (plus, I don't see you closing that stream). Try Files.write(destinationPath, fileBytes)

The first example will automatically close the output file because you use try-with-resources. The second example is missing that.
Besides, what is written to the output file, are you sure it is not an authentication issue during the download?

Thanks @JohannesB, there is no issue with downloading. I am able to download but not able to open.

Also I have tried with below code                                                                                       if (inputStream != null) {
File file = new File(sourceLocation);
Files.copy(inputStream, downloadPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
System.out.println("File downloaded successfully to " + downloadPath);

} else {
System.err.println("Failed to download the file, InputStream is null.");
}

Don't implement that yourself, somebody else already has done it for you ;-)
Try to use Apache Commons IO and use the methods IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream) or IOUtils.copyLarge(InputStream, OutputStream)
You could even use variants of that method where you can specify your own copy-buffer, if you want to tweak the size of that.

I have used above code , but I am faing same issue, I am not able to open the file. it saying like File got corrupted. used the code like try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadPath.toFile())) {
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);  // You can also use IOUtils.copyLarge for large files
logger.info("File downloaded successfully to: " + localPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
logger.error("Error during file download: " + e.getMessage(), e);
throw new Exception("File download failed.", e);

did you try to open the downloaded file with a simple text editor? maybe it's an HTML error page?? If it's an Excel file (XLSX) you should be able to open it with a ZIP program (or just rename it's extension to .zip to open it with windows explorer)
